# Mongo Logs - Duplicate logs in log file

Tags: mongodb, monitoring

We have slow logs enabled on our cluster. I was checking the log file and noticed many duplicate logs. I am providing a sample below. I want to understand the difference between both the log lines, and how it impacts my cluster performance.

LOGS:

> 2016-08-31T09:02:03.872+0000 [conn77463394] update G***d.Users query:
>   { _id: ObjectId('56df9cbb7f6c660dbc086df1') } update: { $set: {
>   u_sess: [ { t_sess: 246, os_key: "ANDROID" } ], moe_ip_address:
>   "*.*.*.*", u_s_c: 245, LastSeen: new Date(1472634072000), moe_ip_pin:
>   400013, moe_dtz: "Asia/Calcutta", u_l_a: new Date(1472634077223) } }
>   nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keyUpdates:0
>   numYields:0 locks(micros) w:619 2206ms
>
> 2016-08-31T09:02:03.872+0000 [conn77463394] command G***d.$cmd
>   command: update { update: "Users", updates: [ { q: { _id:
>   ObjectId('56df9cbb7f6c660dbc086df1') }, u: { $set: { u_sess: [ {
>   t_sess: 246, os_key: "ANDROID" } ], moe_ip_address: "*.*.*.*", u_s_c:
>   245, LastSeen: new Date(1472634072000), moe_ip_pin: 400013, moe_dtz:
>   "Asia/Calcutta", u_l_a: new Date(1472634077223) } }, multi: false,
>   upsert: false } ], ordered: true, metadata: { shardName: "moengagedb",
>   shardVersion: [ Timestamp 0|0, ObjectId('000000000000000000000000') ],
>   session: 0 } } ntoreturn:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0  reslen:155 2206ms